# Clear canvas JavaScript

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas

I'm trying to clear the canvas. I tried closing the path, but it didn't change anything. also, I am not too sure if the ctxBg.close(); is on the right place.
Thank you.

```
function drawGrid () {
    drawGrid();
    ctxBg.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

    function drawGrid () {
        for (var i = 75; i <= canvasWidth-25; i+= 25) {
            ctxBg.beginPath();
            ctxBg.moveTo(-25 + i,55);
            ctxBg.lineTo(-25 + i, canvasHeight - 55);
            ctxBg.stroke();
}

    for (var i = 25; i <= canvasHeight -75; i+= 25) {
        ctxBg.beginPath();
        ctxBg.moveTo(55,25 + i);
        ctxBg.lineTo(canvasWidth-55, 25 + i);
        ctxBg.stroke();      
    }ctxBg.close();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two definitions of the `drawGrid()` function:

```
function drawGrid () {
 ...
 function drawGrid () {
```

You can only have one. Next, there is no `close()` method on a context, only `closePath()`. However, this is not useful here. closePath does not "end" a path, but connects the first and last point in the path so the path *shape* is closed.

This is not useful with lines of course, and in any case, it has to be called before stroke().

Third, you are (attempting to) rendering the grid then clear it right away. This won't show anything on canvas. You need to either separate those operations.

Here's a suggested solution. Two functions, one to draw the grid, one to clear it:

```js
var canvas = document.querySelector("canvas"),
    canvasWidth = canvas.width, canvasHeight = canvas.height,
    ctxBg = canvas.getContext("2d");

ctxBg.translate(0.5, 0.5);  // just to make the lines sharper

function drawGrid() {

  ctxBg.beginPath();   // this can be placed here

  for (var i = 75; i <= canvasWidth - 25; i += 25) {
    ctxBg.moveTo(-25 + i, 55);
    ctxBg.lineTo(-25 + i, canvasHeight - 55);
  }

  for (var i = 25; i <= canvasHeight - 75; i += 25) {
    ctxBg.moveTo(55, 25 + i);
    ctxBg.lineTo(canvasWidth - 55, 25 + i);
  }
  
  ctxBg.stroke();      // stroke all at once
  
  // remove button code (ref. comments)
  var button = document.querySelector("button");
  button.parentNode.removeChild(button);
}

function clearGrid() {
  ctxBg.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
}
```

```html
<button onclick="drawGrid()">Grid</button>
<button onclick="clearGrid()">Clear</button><br>
<canvas></canvas>
```

**Update:** if the button that needs to be removed is a HTML button as in the example above, then remove it by either using style:

```
// assumes the button element is stored in variable button:
button.style.display = "none";
```

or completely, using its `parentNode` and `removeChild()`:

```
button.parentNode.removeChild(button);
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for the answer, I have followed your suggestion on the loop and that works perfectly. I have a button in the middle of the canvas, when the button is clicked it draws the grid but the button stays at the background and the grid on top.

Comment: @MohamedAdel it sounds like you are drawing the button in the canvas itself? Just make sure to draw the button afterwards. If you have a HTML button, check that the button is defined either after the canvas element, or has a z-index (CSS) higher than the canvas (or use a lower z-index than the button).

Comment: i want the button be completely gone after using it to draw the grid, the button is an image with an event, using ctxBg.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height); would it be possible to clear the canvas and then draw the grid without the button on canvas.

Comment: @MohamedAdel yes of course, if drawn into canvas (with ctxBg) just don't redraw it. If a HTML button set its style "display:none" or remove it using its parentNode and removeChild() (this will remove it completely and not just hide it). I updated answer with examples.

Answer (score 0):

```
ctxBg.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
```

This clears your canvas.

Comment: The canvas has a button, when the button is clicked it draws the grid, but when the button is clicked it is still on the canvas with the grid